# why does Eclipse memory analyser not show InetSocketAddress string values?

Tags: java, sockets, heap-dump, inetaddress, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I am analysing a heap dump using eclipse memory analyzer tool. I am trying to list the SocktChannels and their remote addresses. I am unable to see their IP Addresses and the port. I use the following OQL :

`SELECT x.toString() FROM sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl x`

The same string is available when I live debug the application in eclipse - java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/127.0.0.1:3033 remote=/127.0.0.1:54379]
Is there a way to get this information?

[memory analyser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4goS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Memory analyzer doesn't support `toString` methods for all types - only for basic ones. You have to query the exact fields. For example:

```
SELECT x.remoteAddress.holder.addr.holder.hostName.toString() + ":" + x.remoteAddress.holder.port FROM sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl x
```

Comment: thanks. But,I don't see the holder.hostname and holder.port populated at all.